# Сборка приложения vue js в apk

Tags: android, vue.js, apk

Прошел небольшой курс по постройке мобильных приложений на vue js, очень надеялся что в конце покажут самое основное - а именно преобразование приложения в конечный продукт - файл формата apk, но курс закончился и об этом не было сказано ни слова!
В итоге имею простенькое приложение которое открывается в брайзере но вот как его скомпилировать что бы можно было установить на сотовый?
гуглил разные варианты вроде "деплой\компиляция\сборка vue приложения в apk" ничего путного не нашел, подскажите пожалуйста как это делать?

есть директория приложения со стандартной системой папок, запускаю все естественно через нод

Comment: а о чем курс? для сборки в apk вам нужно что-то вроде cordova

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev спасибо) уже допер но теперь там новые проблемы - например при добавлении платформы андроид 2.1 ошибка идет

Comment: @dantebol – ошибки в кордове валятся вечно, она очень капризная ко всему.

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev да уж мне так показалось ещё на этапе установки) но какя альтернатива лучше и проще то https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/938890/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-cordova-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b-android-2-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте Cordova/PhoneGAP если вы хотите просто webview (просто сайт упаковать в приложение)
Если же вам нужны нативные компоненты то рекомендую посмотреть в сторону NativeScript с некоторых пор у них есть поддержка vuejs но шаблоны в данном случаи нужно писать нативные