# Ошибка Cordova при добавлении платформы android 2.1

Tags: vue.js, cordova

Изучаю vue js \ cordova 
и при создании нового приложения и добавления в него платформы так:

```
 cordova platform add android@2.1
```

выдает ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при том то же выдает если указываешь andoid@2.1.0 \ 2.3 \ 4.0.1 
подскажите в чем проблема? в android studio загрузил все доступные версии андроида, может эти просто устарели?

при том если просто добавлять андроид платформу без указания версии - он создает под андроид 7.8 но мне хочется опробовать минимальную доступную версию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По ссылке https://cordova.apache.org/docs/ru/latest/guide/platforms/android/ :

> Cordova поддерживает Android 4.0.x (начиная с уровня Android API 14) и
>   выше. Как правило версии Android перестают поддерживается Cordova
>   после того как они опустится ниже 5% на панель распространения Google.
>   Версии Android менее чем API уровня 10, и версии 3.x (Honeycomb,
>   уровни API 11-13) упали значительно ниже этого 5%-го порога.

Android 2.1 - это API 7

Это очень старая версия.

Обычно поддерживают Android 4.1 - API 16 и выше.

Comment: Да уж, я подозревал об этом\ А можно каким то образом установить старую версию кордовы и что бы она работала со старыми версиями?

Comment: Если только поставить более старую кордову. Список версий: npm view cordova versions; установка одной из старых версии: npm install -g cordova@5.2.0. Экспериментируйте, ставьте старую версию и пробуйте в ней создать android проект 2.1, если не получится - надо ставить старше, и так далее.

Comment: да так и есть спасибо) на этйо версии устанавливается нормально 4й дроид, но вот не хочет запускать build просто ничего не происходит\ попробую более поздние версии

Comment: ещё такой вопрос - есть ли альтернатива кордове? что бы так же кросплатформенно собирать приложения на vue js ? может есть что то менее капризное?